# Calendar synchronisation

Tags: outlook

I don't understand why on my ribbon's SharePoint, the feature "connect to outlook" is disabled... 
[image]Could you help me? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Internet Explorer Options -> Security tab -> click on Internet zone and uncheck Enhanced Protected Mode

Then either refresh the page, either restart IE.

source :[click Here](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/172/t/119545.aspx)

Comment: if it helped you than you can upvote and mark my answer